Function to extract sub-statements from overall statement with LLMs
I have the following situation: I have a statement (max. 130 characters), e.g.

"I like blue benches and I like to walk with my dog but sometimes I
just need to go biking"

I just wonder wehether there exist functions / packages / algorithms which are able to extract the sub-statements, i.e. return 3 statements

"I like blue benches"
"I like to walk with my dog"
"I just need to go biking"

I haven't been able to find anything yet, but maybe I'm missing the right keyword...
